Compute KL divergence between a mixture of Gaussians and a Gaussian prior in (rank-1) Bayesian neural networks?
I'm working on a rank-1 Bayesian Neural Network in Pytorch (more specifically, trying to replicate the results from Efficient and Scalable Bayesian Neural Nets with Rank-1 Factors).
In short, only the rank-1 weights (fast weights) are treated as stochastic while the remaining weights are deterministic as usual. For the regularization term in the loss function, I need to compute the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence between the approximate posterior and the Gaussian prior - however, they mention using a mixture approximate posterior (of Gaussians (MoG)), where the components are weighed equally. I understand that the exact KL divergence between a MoG and a single Gaussian does not have a closed-form solution, so how do I go about this?
My current approach is as follows:

Compute the KL divergence for each Gaussian component in the mixture relative to the Gaussian prior.
Sum the divergences
Divide by number of ensemble members (number of mixture components).

*My question is therefore: *
Is this approach of approximating the KL divergence between a mixture of Gaussians and a Gaussian prior valid? Are there any potential issues or better methods to compute this divergence efficiently in the context of Bayesian neural networks?
